# CSS Animation: Load second keyframe after first

Tags: animation, css, keyframe, css-animations

I study CSS Animations and I have a question.

This is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MBJbB/
**Note:** Work only in WebKit browsers.

I have 2 keyframes. I set "first" to repeat 3 times.

After running the "first" keyframe of the 3 times, I wanted to call the "second" infinite times.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: joshuanhibbert's answer is more elegant. Use it.**

```
$("#ball").bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function(){
  $(this).addClass("infinite");
});
```

And your CSS

```
#ball.infinite {
  -webkit-animation: second 1s ease-in 0 infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: second 1s ease-in 0 infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: second 1s ease-in 0 infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: second 1s ease-in 0 infinite alternate;
  animation: second 1s ease-in 0 infinite alternate;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K74TW/

Comment: Thanks, it works! In Mozilla simply change to mozAnimationEnd?

Comment: Mozilla's version is animationend. I edited the answer to future proof it when Opera supports animations, and hopefully someday IE too.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely true, you do not need JS for this. It is easily done using CSS, see my answer.